# How to run a gitlab job except a variable has some value?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to run a gitlab job in every case EXCEPT the variable `RUN` is defined and contains the value `run3`.

So again:

- variable `RUN` is undefined: run the job
- variable `RUN` is defined and does not contain the value `run3`: run the job
- variable `RUN` is defined and does contain the value `run3`: DO NOT run the job

I tried the following rules:

```
  rules:
    - if: $RUN != null && $RUN == "run3"
      when: never

  rules:
    - if: $RUN != "" && $RUN == "run3"
      when: never

  rules:
    - if: $RUN == "run3"
      when: never
```

Without the variable `RUN` being defined, no job was run. I expected the job to have been run.

How to fix it? Where is the problem in the logic?

Answer (score 4):

After some time-consuming try-and-error trials I found the solution: As you cannot test if a variable exists, you have to create the rule the other way around. It means, you run the job if the value does not match:

The correct rule is then:

```
- if: $RUN != "run3"
  when: always
- when: never
```

The first part only evaluates to `true` if the variable exists AND if the variable does not evaluate to `run3`. In that case the job is run.

The second part then tells to NOT run the job in any other case.

Comment: Well. This may _work_ but may have unintended side-effects when you use `always` -- it will run even if jobs in the previous stage fail. You probably want to be using `on_success` instead of `always` and perhaps invert the rule to make it behave normally and more descriptive of the condition.

Comment: How to invert the rule? I am not sure that will work as I did find out.

Comment: All I mean is to use `$RUN == "run3"` and `when: on_success` instead of the opposite. I described this in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You're close

```yaml
  rules:
    - if: $RUN == "run3"
      when: never
```

This is correct, but you also need a default `- when:`

To emulate the default behavior of no rules when the first rule does not match, set the default as `on_success`

```yaml
  rules:
    - if: $RUN == "run3"
      when: never # don't run the job in this case
    - when: on_success  # run per usual in all other cases
```